# Can we parameterize the request file name to the Read method in Karate?

Tags: java, web-services, cucumber, karate

As I'm trying to automate the API testing process, have to pass the XML file to **Read** method for example,

```
Given request read ( varXmlFile )
```

**FYI:** XML file is present in the same folder where the feature file exists.

Doing this, its throwing an exception like this

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: called: D:\workspace\APIAutomationDemo\target\test-classes\com\org\features\rci_api_testing.feature, scenario: Get Membership Details, line: 15
javascript evaluation failed: read (varXmlFile )
```

So Karate doesn't allow this way or can we have any other alternative ?

Suggestion please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure the variable is set:

```
* def varXmlFile = 'some-xml-file.xml'
Given request read(varXmlFile)
```

Or just use normally:

```
Given request read('some-xml-file.xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem got solved as in the variable **varXmlFile** holds the file name along with single quote like this **'SampleXmlRequest.xml'**.

So I removed the single quote while returning from the method.